# Should we have to repeat the possessive determiner in a list?

Tags: ellipsis, determiners, coordination

Is it better to put:

> Snow white was so pretty with *her* blood-red lips, **her** fair skin and **her** black hair.

or

> Snow White was so pretty with *her* blood-red lips, fair skin and black hair.

Comment: No repetition is needed.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it better to put:

It's not better. It's also not worse.

You can use either interchangeably. The repetition is unnecessary- so most people would probably opt for the shorter version. Both are technically correct.